# Snort Error: Active response: can't open ip

Tags: windows, config, snort

I am trying to run snort on windows as newbie. I have followed [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2w-fbyy6y0) to start off. After completing all steps, when I try to test configuration file, it gives me above error. I am running cmd in Administrator mode. Is there anything else I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was making a simple mistake of not including interface in command. 
I had to use `snort -i 1 c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -T` while I was mistakenly executing `snort c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -T`.

Answer (score 0):

You also may to run snort with --daq pcap